# Linear Programming in LaTeX

Tags: equations, arrays, sharelatex

Currently I am doing a project in Linear Programming. In connection with this I want to explain some theory (very short) but I am having a hard time making the expression below. Can anyone help me doing this.[image]

Comment: I see no reason for aligning the terms in the objective function with the terms in the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lr@{}c@{}r@{}l}
\text{maximize }   & c_1 x_1   & {}+{\dots}+{} & c_n x_n   &           \\
\text{subject to } & a_{11}x_1 & {}+{\dots}+{} & a_{1n}x_n & {}\le b_1 \\
                   &           &     \vdots    &           &           \\
                   & a_{m1}x_1 & {}+{\dots}+{} & a_{mn}x_n & {}\le b_m 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thats great! How can I make the \vdots right under the \cdots?

Comment: @AlimTeacher : Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started...

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{maximize } \quad & c_1 x_1 + \dots + c_n x_n \\
\text{subject to }\quad &
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} x_1 + \dots + a_{1n} x_n \leq b_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_{m1} x_1 + \dots + a_{mn} x_n \leq b_m 
\end{array}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```